# No check runs for check suite app in Github Webhooks

Tags: github, github-actions, github-webhook

I have a webhook for capturing `check-suite` events from my GitHub repository. In the list of check-suites for a commit, there is one from **dependabot** which has the status `queued` and with a conclusion `null`. Dependbaot has been enabled for this repository. I checked for the check runs associated with this commit and there are none.

Here is the API response for the check-suite searched by check-suite ID:

```
{
    "id": 19496120783,
    "node_id": "...",
    "head_branch": "dev",
    "head_sha": "abc",
    "status": "queued",
    "conclusion": null,
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/X/Y/check-suites/19496120783",
    "before": "xyz",
    "after": "lmn",
    "pull_requests": [
        {
            "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/X/Y/pulls/123",
            ...
        }
    ],
    "app": {
        "id": 1,
        "slug": "dependabot",
        "node_id": "..",
..
}
```

Here is the check-runs API response for the above check-suite

```
{
    "total_count": 0,
    "check_runs": []
}
```

What could be causing a check-suite of this sort to be created? I have other repositories with  I have some logic written in my webhook that does further processing only when all check-suites have concluded successfully and this one is problematic.

I tried to re-run the check-suite but the docs specify that apps must have the `checks: read` permission and it not possible to add `checks` permission explicitly. What could be triggering this check-suite?